# Find bytes at specific position PYTHON

Tags: python, indexing, serial-port, position, byte

I have a simple function to read bytes from serial port.

Simply code looks like

`read_bytes = serial.read(5)`

After that I print a result and for example I have

`b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'`

There is an option to catch bytes at specific position ? For example If I want to print byte at second position it should print for me `b'\x02'`. I read documentation but functions `find` and `index` do different stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the  `bytes` class as an iterable, and you can access its elements as you would with a simple string like:

```
read_bytes = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'
read_bytes[2]
# 3
read_bytes[0]
# 1
```

So just use list indexing to access an element with a specific index.

#### Update:

In case you want to retrieve the element as a `bytes` object you can slice it from the sequence:

```
read_bytes[2:3]
# b'\x03'
read_bytes[0:1]
# b'\x01'
```

A more verbose way is to get the element and cast it as `bytes`

```
bytes([read_bytes[2]])
```

**Note:** you have to pass the value in an iterable otherwise `bytes` will return a sequence of null bytes with a length of the integer value it received.

Comment: so there in no normal function to find this index buildin bytes ?

Comment: @BengBeng: this is a normal function of indexed objects.

Comment: how can I use list function on bytes ?

Comment: @BengBeng what do you mean by list function? If you want to cast `bytes` to `list` just apply `list(read_bytes)` and then you get a list of integers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He is asking how to retrieve the byte at specific position, your solution retrieves the integer form of the byte, not the byte itself.

Comment: @Bersan what is a byte in your dictionary? To me a byte is an integer between 0 and 255 or  -128 and 127. Or with other words a byte is an integer represented by 8 bits, let it be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Szabolcs `bytes` and `int` in python are 2 different types

Comment: @Bersan thank you for pointing that out. However you were referring to a byte and not the `bytes` type in your comment.